# Django filter question - How to delete a single item with the most recent date?

Tags: django, django-filter

I have 1 db, Master that effectively has a composite primary key, of ID and date, My system allows deletion from this db for some users. What I am trying to do is have them enter an ID, and then it deletes the row with that ID, but only the most recent date.

I have tried filtering for the ID, and then chaining the latest method, I have also tried using the order by and selecting the first entry.

```py
toDelete = Master.objects.filter(Identifier=id).latest('EffectiveDate')
toDelete.delete()
```

This statement, when I call delete, deletes all of the entries in the db which match the ID, I am trying to have it only delete the last one to occur.

Comment: Can you post you Master model.py?

Comment: `toDelete` normally should here be an *object*, not a queryset. Can you print the type of `toDelete`?

Answer (score 2):

This should give you the newest by date which you can then delete:

```
toDelete = Master.objects.filter(Identifier=id).order_by('-EffectiveDate')[0]
toDelete.delete()
```

Comment: This still is deleting all of the entries where Identifier is id. IS there any other way to do it?

Comment: This should not be deleting more than one entry, as only the first entry is returned from the list by the `[0]`. What do you get if you `print(toDelete)`?

Comment: I get The ID and the latest date (what my __str__ method for that model should display, but it is still deleting all of the entries where Identifier is id. Is there anything I have to do to setup a composite key, apart from in the model having in the Meta class for my model:

```python
 unique_together = (('Identifier', 'EffectiveDate'),)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you want to fetch only first record, you could use:

```
toDelete = Master.objects.filter(Identifier=id).latest('EffectiveDate').first()
toDelete.delete()
```

The line- `Master.objects.filter(Identifier=id).latest('EffectiveDate')`
returns the identity of that record(not just the record), hence when you call delete-, it deletes all occurances and not just the first. 
More  [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#first)

Answer (score 0):

If you have create_date(which saves the time of the creation of data) field in your model like:

```
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

then you can try:

```
toDelete = Master.objects.filter(Identifier=id).order_by('-create_date')
if toDelete:
    toDelete = toDelete[0]
    toDelete.delete()
```

Comment: In your case, I think `EffectiveDate` is equivalent to `create_date`...